# Robosuite importing in pycharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm

i am trying to use robosuite on pycharm, and have an error of "No module named 'robosuite.macros_private' " while trying to import robosuite even after I installed it correctly. After tracing the error I found the the following ROBOSUITE_DEFAULT_LOGGER.warn("No private macro file found!")
ROBOSUITE_DEFAULT_LOGGER.warn("It is recommended to use a private macro file")
ROBOSUITE_DEFAULT_LOGGER.warn("To setup, run: python {}/scripts/setup_macros.py".format(robosuite.path[0]))
,but I don't know how to create a private macro.

I tried cloning the robosuite also but got the same error.